# Accessing <video> src from the domain I don't own

Tags: python, html, flask, html5-video, cross-domain

I get an error when Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.com (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I'm trying to stream the video from a domain that I don't own.

```
<html>
<video src="https://1fgqfvr.oloadcdn.net/dl/l/Qs0QJALKTJ2zxVmk/E3vkxyI6bEw/The+Beyond+%282018%29.mp4?mime=true" class="class=&quot;video-js" vjs-default-skin="" vjs-big-play-centered"="" crossorigin="anonymous" controls="" autoplay="" height="100%" width="100%">
    <track kind="captions" srclang="en" label="▤ Load SRT/VTT from PC~PC~" class="olsrt">
    <track kind="captions" srclang="en" label="▤ Load SRT/VTT from URL~URL~">
    </video>
</html>
```

The src is the downlodable file. What other ways can i work this out?

```
crossorigin="anonymous"
```

I thought that would've solved my issue but it didn't.

I'm on flask.

Comment: The sever owner for 1fgqfvr.oloadcdn.net didn't enable CORS. So they're the ones stopping you from loading the video. When you download, you don't worry about CORS, but when doing a cross domain request, the browser stops it for security reasons.